# R Shiny : Leaflet Map getting greyed out on using addDrawToolbar in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm trying to use "addDrawToolbar" function from lealfet.extras packages.
The code for the same looks like this :

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldStreetMap")%>%
      addDrawToolbar(
        targetGroup='Selected',
        polylineOptions=FALSE,
        markerOptions = FALSE,
        polygonOptions = drawPolygonOptions(shapeOptions=drawShapeOptions(fillOpacity = 0
                                                                          ,color = 'red'
                                                                          ,weight = 3)),
        rectangleOptions = drawRectangleOptions(shapeOptions=drawShapeOptions(fillOpacity = 0
                                                                              ,color = 'red'
                                                                              ,weight = 3,clickable = TRUE)),
        editOptions = editToolbarOptions(edit = TRUE, selectedPathOptions = selectedPathOptions()))})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So the issue is when i'm trying to run the script in the browser, the map is getting greyed out and nothing shows up.

[Should be a leaflet image inside the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edwhw.jpg)

But, when i'm commenting out the queries from "addDrawToolbar"  function or running it from R console (only the leaflet query), its working fine i.e. in former, i'm able to see background map and in latter, i'm able to draw custom rectangular/polygon extent.

I want to achieve the same in Shiny browser but unable to do so.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a fully reproducible example of your problem ? Because this piece of code seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Just edited your code and made a reproducible example out of it. The code also works fine for me. Maybe update `shiny / leaflet / leaflet.extras`, if the code doesnt work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Basically, i'm creating a windows batch file and then running the executable.  
And when i'm doing so, im facing the issue